# How to change photo storage path for LineageOS 16's Camera app?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, camera, lineageos

I am running the latest LineageOS 16.0, and have specified `SD Card` as my photo storage location for the built-in Camera app.

When I was using LineageOS 15.1, the app saved photos on my SD card's "DCIM" directory, but in 16.0, the app now saves photos in "Android/data/org.lineageos.snap/files/" (also on my SD card).

Is there a way to change the path back to "DCIM"?

Thank you!

Comment: Huge thanks for pointing out the data directory! That saved me a lot of photos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of right now it is not possible for you to change the path. Android Pie does not allow apps to write/read SD Card public area and only allows apps to access the application private area.
That being said inside of Lineage OS Gitlab Repository there are several discussions to fix this problem. Maybe it will be fixed in the future with an update of Lineage or the integrated camera App.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, appreciate the insight! That said, I wonder if a stop-gap measure would be to create a symbolic link from the old DCIM directory to the application data area used by the Camera app?

Answer (score 3):

Know this was a couple of months ago, and you may have found the solution.  But I came across this very problem and the above info is mostly correct, you need **Open Camera**;

From https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/issues/268

> I don't know why Snap can't do it but in Open Camera > Settings > More
>   Camera Controls > toggle on **Use Storage Access Framework** then navigate
>   to /storage/Micro SD card id/DCIM/Camera & Save Location.
>
> That works on S5 G900M LineageOS 16.0 klte build 2019-04-02 + Open
>   GApps Pico + LineageOS Addonsu.

Works on my Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running LineageOS 16.0-20191129-UNOFFICIAL-trlte